# Should I avoid to use L2 regularization in conjuntion with RMSProp?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Should I avoid to use L2 regularization in conjuntion with RMSprop and NAG?

The L2 regularization term interferes with the gradient algorithm (RMSprop)?

Best reggards,

Comment: Any good reasons to draw this conclusion?

Comment: Training one layer + softmax output with conjugate gradient more L2 regularization leads to better prediction accuracy, with RMSProp or NAG more L2 regularization leads to worst prediction accuracy.

Comment: That is not a good reason. It's a very broad and non-scientific statement with many possible explanations (which we can't give because we don't know anythong about your data or benchmark-setup). And are you really using CG? Not Gradient-descent / Stochastis-Gradient-Descent? Well... I just would not draw this conclusion as you do. But feel free to try every Optimizer there is. If you got the time, tune vanilla-SGD (maybe incl. momentum).

Comment: Sorry I give further explanation. Prediction over 3 seassons of socker league with similiar accuracy, in different seassons, for same tested gradient algorithms (conjugate, adagrad, rmsprop, nesterov). Without regularization L2 the best mark on prediction accuracy is for nesterov, but with regularization L2 the best mark is for conjugate (better than conjugate without L2) meanwhile the nesterov or rmsprop get worst accuracy than before.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that someone have sorted out (2018) the question (2017).

Vanilla adaptive gradients (RMSProp, Adagrad, Adam, etc) do not match well with L2 regularization.

Link to the paper [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05101.pdf] and some intro:

> In this paper, we show that a
>   major factor of the poor generalization of the most popular
>   adaptive gradient method, Adam, is due to the fact that L2
>   regularization is not nearly as effective for it as for SGD.
>
> L2 regularization and weight decay are not identical.
>   Contrary to common belief, the two techniques are not
>   equivalent. For SGD, they can be made equivalent by
>   a reparameterization of the weight decay factor based
>   on the learning rate; this is not the case for Adam. **In
>   particular, when combined with adaptive gradients, L2
>   regularization leads to weights with large gradients
>   being regularized less than they would be when using
>   weight decay.**